# Why do I get 'PdfReadError: EOF marker not found'?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, pypdf

I am downloading multiple PDFs. I have a list of urls and the code is written to download them and also create one big pdf with them all in. The code works for the first 144 pdfs then it throws this error:

> PdfReadError: EOF marker not found

I've tried making all the pdfs end in %%EOF but that doesn't work - it still reaches the same point then I get the error again.

Here's my code:

## my file and converting to list for python to read each separately

```
with open('minutelinks.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read() 
links = data.split()
```

## download pdfs

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import requests
urls = links 

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    title = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(title, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        merger.append(title)

merger.write("allminues.pdf")
merger.close()
```

I want to be able to download all of them and create one big pdf - which it appears to do until it throws this error. I have about 750 pdfs and it only gets to 144.

Comment: Do some basic debugging: Use `try`/`except` and catch the exception. This will tell you the file that's causing the problem — you can check its content. You could also try to continue and see if it's just that one file.

Comment: What line of my code would this go in? Sorry I'm new to coding.

Comment: The traceback should tell you the line that's raising the exception. Put the `try` on the line before the line that's causing the error. Indent the line. After it, un-indent and put an `except PdfReadError:`. After that, indented, you can `print(title)`, then after that call `sys.exit()` to quit or leave that out and it will go on to the next one. The basics are [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Comment: It looks like that particular PDF is corrupted. And you can't fix a PDF by adding stuff at the end in a text editor.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I've sorted it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I changed my code so it now downloads all of the pdfs and skips the one (or more) that may be correupted. I also had to add the `self` argument to the function.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import requests
import sys

urls = links 

def download_pdfs(self):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for url in urls:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url)
            title = url.split("/")[-1]
            with open(title, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
        except PdfReadError:
            print(title) 
            sys.exit()
    merger.append(title)

    merger.write("allminues.pdf")
    merger.close()
```

Comment: Totally your call, of course, but I would suggest printing an error message when a `PdfReadError` occurs (as well as the `title` or `url`). It's also not clear why you needed to add the `self` argument since the function is not a class method and doesn't reference the argument anywhere.

Comment: Also, your code will not continue if a `PdfReadError` occurs — it exits. Leave the `sys.exit()` call out if you want it to continue processing the remaining urls.

Comment: One final comment. You might be able to avoid the error altogether (if it's something minor) by specifying `merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)` (based on the class' [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileMerger.html)).

Comment: I'm getting NameError: name 'PdfReadError' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The end of file marker '%%EOF' is meant to be the very last line. It is a kind of marker where the pdf parser knows, that the PDF document ends here.

My solution is to force this marker to stay at the end:

```
def reset_eof(self, pdf_file):
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as p:
        txt = (p.readlines())
    for i, x in enumerate(txt[::-1]):
        if b'%%EOF' in x:
            actual_line = len(txt)-i-1
            break
    txtx = txt[:actual_line] + [b'%%EOF']
    with open(pdf_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines(txtx)
    return PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
```

Comment: `actual_line` doesn't exist in case of `b'%%EOF' not in x`. But I suppose in this case the PDF doesn't contain an EOF for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

I read that EOF is a kind of tag included in PDF files. [link in portuguese](https://living-sun.com/pt/python/724834-eof-marker-not-found-while-use-pypdf2-merge-pdf-file-in-python-python-pdf-pypdf2.html)

However, I guess some kinds of PDF files do not have the 'EOF marker' and PyPDF2 do not recognizes those ones.

So, what I did to fix "PdfReadError: EOF marker not found" was opening my PDF with Google Chromer and print it as .pdf once more, so that the file is converted to .pdf by Chromer and hopefully with the EOF marker.

I ran my script with the new .pdf file converted by Chromer and it worked fine.